# C# cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#, random

I want use "Random rnd = new Random();"

```
public int dzien;

private void generator_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Random rnd = new Random();

 dzien = rnd.Next(1, 11);      
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("birthDateDay").SetAttribute("value", dzien);
}
```

And when i want run program i got error:

cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

This is in line "webBrowser1...." on "dzien".

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to create a new Random each Tick

Comment: Please make sure to read [MCVE] guidance before asking future questions - i.e.sample code for this question should be single line: `string valueForSetAttribute = 42;` (not that would make question on-topic on SO as searching for exact title of the post or error message would give you an answer already - https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+cannot+convert+from+%27int%27+to+%27string%27)

Answer (score 4):

Change `dzien` to `dzien.ToString()`. The `SetAttribute` method takes a string and you're trying to pass an integer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `dzien` with `dzien.ToString()`. The `setAttribute` function requires two strings as arguments but you've given it a string and an integer.

Comment: That's `.ToString()`. :)

Comment: Oops! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This happening because setAttribute() method wants string as parameters and it not able to implicitly convert int to string. So simple replace your code with below line of code.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("birthDateDay").SetAttribute("value", ""+dzien);
```